# How to open a webpage if it isn't already open, and if it is, switch to it instead?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer, batch-file

I am currently executing this command in my batch file `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://localhost"` to open up my page in Internet Explorer after generating it and copying it.

However, if I already have the page open, it opens a second window. How can I prevent this by making it switch to the existing window or tab?

Comment: only the browser itself can make this choice. a http connection is a one-off kinda thing, and once the GET command has gotten a response that the browser has rendered, you don't have a connection to the server anymore, so the only way you can tell is to check each tab in each window to determine whether one of them had previously loaded the URL. that means it will be very hard to accomplish from the command line unless the IE executable takes an option telling it to look first, which it likely doesn't.