# when opening a link in firefox, go to tab where webpage is already open, otherwise open new tab

Tags: firefox, tabs

##### psuedo code / desired behaviour

```
When I click on a link (on a webpage in the firefox web browser)
if there is a tab that has the same url as the link I clicked on:
  switch to that tab
else:
  open link in new tab (default)
```

##### Existing work-arounds

- When I start typing in a link in the search bar, Firefox will suggest switching to a tab where it might already be open.
- However my requirements are for a similar behaviour but for when I click on links.

### Why?

- I'm doing a lot of research and clicking a lot of links that might be the same.
- I want to prevent opening unnecessary tabs, it should go to the tab where the page is already open/loaded

---

##### Related (kind of) but not duplicate of

- [How to open a webpage if it isn't already open, and if it is, switch to it instead?](https://superuser.com/questions/766509/how-to-open-a-webpage-if-it-isnt-already-open-and-if-it-is-switch-to-it-inste)

  - The end result is similar, but the method is based on executing commands in a batch file on Win8.1.
  - My requirements are purely for when inside the Firefox browser.
- [How to prevent firefox from switching to a tab thats already open when I want to open the same webpage on a different browser/tab](https://superuser.com/questions/1654727/how-to-prevent-firefox-from-switching-to-a-tab-thats-already-open-when-i-want-to)

  - The title is similar, but the requirements are more regarding the search bar's behaviour when typing in a url that's already open in another tab.
  - my requirements are focused on the browser's behaviour when clicking on a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is not built-into Firefox, so you should look for
an add-on.

Here are some add-ons that relate to your post:

- [Duplicate Tabs Closer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
  Perhaps to be used with option "On duplicate tab detected" set as
  "Close tab automatically:", and option "On remaining tab" set as
  "Activate".
- [Duplicate Tabs Closer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duplicate-tabs-closer-updated/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
  A fork of the previous add-on.
- [Tab Deduper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-deduper/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)
  "Whenever a tab's URL changes, it is checked against the current window's existing tabs. On a match, one is made active and the other is removed."
- [Smart Prevent Duplicate Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smart-prevent-duplicate-tabs/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)

Comment: The first option worked perfectly! (coincidentally I already had the first option installed)